# CrossListQueryInfo how to specify lists instead of id's or types

Tags: list, cross-list, crosslistqueryinfo

I have a question regarding the CrosListSueryInfo and how can i specify the name of the list instead of type or template or id ...

On msdn as example there is following:

```
CrossListQueryInfo crossListInfo = new CrossListQueryInfo();
                crossListInfo.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" Nullable=\"True\" Type=\"Text\"/><FieldRef Name=\"FileRef\"/>";
                crossListInfo.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"File_x0020_Type\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">aspx</Value></Eq>" +
                                      "<Neq><FieldRef Name=\"ContentType\"/><Value Type=\"String\">Article Page</Value></Neq></And></Where>" +
                                      "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Created\" Type=\"DateTime\" Ascending=\"True\"/></OrderBy>";
                crossListInfo.RowLimit = 15;
                crossListInfo.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"Recursive\" />";
                crossListInfo.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"850\">";
                crossListInfo.WebUrl = "/";
```

But they specify there a template, but i would like to say the list name/title.

I know i can also specify id, like that: `<Lists ServerTemplate='100'><List ID='{ID}'/></Lists>`

But i still need title, any idea how to do it?

And is it also possible to do with ContentTypeId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to specify list titles. You can only specify list templates and list IDs.

Comment: Yes, it is not possible, so i just used a where and put there by contenttype ...